# Access Bootstrap in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsfiddle

I am building [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ku6zrt7v/1/) project in jsfiddle. I have imported the bootstrap resources I saw other people use, but bootstrap is not applying. For example, the submit button looks as follows:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-login" id="login-button">
```

But in practice, it is a standard html button. I also tried to create three columns across the top like so:

```
<div className="col-md-4">
    <p>
    fil 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-4">
    <p>
    fil 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div className="col-md-4">
    <p>
    fil 
    </p>
  </div>
```

But they end up just stacking on each other, rather than filling out the column. I have `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js`. Am I missing any resources? How can I get bootstrap to function in this fiddle?

Comment: Press F12 and look at the errors in the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bootstrap CDN you linked in the External Resources on you JSfiddle is broken.

try use these ones

CSS: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

jQuery: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

JS: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: I'm sorry, but there aren't any links here. Can you please post them?

Comment: This is not a good practice to add static resource in jsfiddle like this, infact jsfiddle gives your warning for the same. You can just use external resource option and paste URL's for your static resources.

Comment: @GirdhariAgrawal Can you expound on what the correct practice is?

Comment: @GirdhariAgrawal that's what I was doing. I think this was just his way of presenting the proper external resources to me.

Comment: Thats what I was trying to suggest here. Putting the link in src="" into the external uri in JSfiddle. Im not sure why you saying its bad

Comment: I was trying the same thing you mentioned and jsfiddle was giving suggestion/warning to use external resource option. That's why I said it's not a good practice.
**Warning:** `For external CSS files use the Resources panel on the left.`

Comment: @Yuhao change the format to links only (also, you could add jQuery CDN for making your answer more correct) and everyone happy.